# How to test a function which throws exception, in Dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

Say I have a function which throws exception:

```dart
hello() {
    throw "exception of world";
}
```

I want to test it, so I write a test:

```dart
test("function hello should throw exception", () {
    expect(()=>hello(), throwsA("exception of world"));
});
```

You can see I didn't call `hello()` directly, instead, I use `()=>hello()`.

It works but I wonder if is there any other way to write tests for it?

Comment: It's worth noting that if your method under test had parameters, you would still have to use the lambda syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `hello` directly by name instead of creating a closure that only calls `hello`.

This unit-test passes:

```dart
main() {
  test("function hello should throw exception", () {
      expect(hello, throwsA(new isInstanceOf<String>()));
  });
}
```

Comment: This reminds me of `list.forEach((e)=>print(e));` when it's fine to say `list.forEach(print);`

Comment: For `list.forEach(print)`, it's a very useful tip, I'm looking for it these days

Answer (score 4):

This article explains  how to test exceptions https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/master/pkgs/test/README.md#asynchronous-tests

```
test("function hello should throw exception", () {
    expect(hello, throwsA(quals("exception of world")));
});
```

Comment: I've read that article, and my main problem is "Do I have to add `()=>` for my function? Is it the only workable way?". That article doesn't answer this

Comment: I can't take a closer look until monday. I have only occassional internet connection here.

Comment: I think Ganymedes answer is what you were looking for, isn't it?

Comment: this link is not an article.  it just forwards to here: https://github.com/dart-lang/test#writing-tests

Comment: @jayhendren thanks for the hint! I updated my answer.